# Trying to size correctly android layouts

Tags: android, android-layout, android-xml

I'm struggling on a layout management so I decided to ask here.
I would like to get 3 layouts working in a certain way.
I have 3 views vertically dispatched into a RelativeLayout (let's call them VTop, VMiddle and VBottom).

VBottom is a Button, I want him to stay aligned with the bottom of the screen and to never move or get resized (actually working).

VMiddle is a scroll view. I want this ScrollView to take all possible place between the bottom button (VBottom) and the top most layout (VTop) but never having it height inferior to an specific size.

I would like to have VTop (A linear layout containing some TextViews and other stuffs) wrapping all of its content as long as VMiddle doesn't get smaller that its minimum size.

Actually the code I have is almost working but when I Inflate too much content into VMiddle, it keeps growing towards the top of the screen and VTop completely disappear. I want VMiddle to stay at it minimum size if VTop doesn't have enough space to wrap his content.

[image: Problem Schema]

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/relativeLayout1">
    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/linearLayout1" <!-- VTop -->
        android:layout_above="@+id/eventDetail_RateLayout"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_margin="10sp"> <!-- LOT OF VIEWS, NEED TO BE WRAPPED AS MUCH AS POSSIBLE --> 
    </LinearLayout>
    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="100px"
        android:id="@+id/eventDetail_RateLayout" <!-- Not visible for now, you can ignore it -->
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
        android:minWidth="25px"
        android:minHeight="25px"
        android:background="@color/common_google_signin_btn_text_light_default"
        android:layout_above="@+id/eventDetail_CommentScrollView"
        android:visibility="gone" />
    <ScrollView
        android:id="@+id/eventDetail_CommentScrollView" <!-- VMiddle -->
        android:background="#4D4A58"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_above="@+id/eventDetail_commentButton">
        <LinearLayout
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:minWidth="25px"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/eventDetail_CommentLayout" />
    </ScrollView>
    <Button
        android:text="commenter"
        android:id="@+id/eventDetail_commentButton" <!-- VMiddle, this one is doing ok -->
        android:background="#666"
        android:textColor="#f8f8f8"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="30sp"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Thanks for your answers.

Comment: Use weights....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally achieved to get something close to what I wanted. I combined layout_above and below and fixed the size of VTop by making the Huge TextView scrollable. I have now VTop and VBottom at a fixed size and VMiddle taking the rest of the place at the center.

Thanks for your fast answers :)

Answer (score 0):

Try the following code for the `ScrollView` -

```
    <ScrollView
        android:id="@+id/eventDetail_CommentScrollView" <!-- VMiddle -->
        android:background="#4D4A58"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_below="@id/linearLayout1"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_above="@+id/eventDetail_commentButton">
...
    </ScrollView>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this, however the kind of UI you want can be easily achieved using Linear layout and using weight and weightSum properties.. also rename ID of the layout and views accordingly

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/topLayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:background="#70AD47"
        android:orientation="vertical">

    </LinearLayout>

    <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_above="@+id/btnBottom"
        android:layout_below="@+id/topLayout"
        android:background="#ED7D31"
        android:minHeight="400dp">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical">

        </LinearLayout>

    </ScrollView>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnBottom"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:background="#4472C4"
        android:text="Bottom button" />


</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: I was initially using LinearLayout but I swapped to a Relative one cause I didn't managed to get the View to react the way I wanted to. However, I didn't tried to use the weight_sum property, I'll check this out, thx.

Comment: @Jasone.L sure, I hope it helped.

Answer (score 0):

**1.** Add attribute `android:layout_below="@id/linearLayout1"` and `android:layout_above="@id/eventDetail_commentButton"` to `ScrollView` to keep it at middle position.

**2.** Use `ScrollView` and its child `LinearLayout` height `android:layout_width="match_parent"` although its not necessary.

No matter how big the `top` and `bottom` layout, middle `scrollview` will always fill the middle free spaces. It will never change the `height` of `top` and `bottom` layout.

**Here is the working layout:**

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/relativeLayout1">

    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/linearLayout1"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_margin="10sp">

    </LinearLayout>

    <Button
        android:text="commenter"
        android:id="@+id/eventDetail_commentButton"
        android:background="#666"
        android:textColor="#f8f8f8"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="30sp"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true" />

    <ScrollView
        android:id="@+id/eventDetail_CommentScrollView"
        android:background="#4D4A58"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_below="@id/linearLayout1"
        android:layout_above="@id/eventDetail_commentButton">

        <LinearLayout
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:minWidth="25px"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:id="@+id/eventDetail_CommentLayout" />
    </ScrollView>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Hope this will help~

Comment: Hey, thx for your answer. I already tried every tricks combining layout above and bellow and espacially your exact proposition. But with this fix, VTop is always wrapped but VMiddle disapear when VTop takes too much place no matter what minimum size I set to VMiddle (the property min_hieght is totally ignore on VMiddle in this case) :/

Comment: set minheight  to  top layout not  to middle layout.

Answer (score 0):

Use android:layout_below="@+id/linearlayout1"
in eventDetail_RateLayout

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure none of the given answers achieve what you're looking for. What you wanna do is not simple because it involves a circular dependency: you basically want your `vTop` view to wrap and fill any space left by your `vMiddle` view (`android:layout_above="@id/vMiddle"`) and at the same time you want your `vMiddle` view to wrap and fill any space left by your `vTop` view (`android:layout_below="@id/vTop"`).
The only solution I can imagine would be to check and set the view sizes programmatically, I don't think this is doable only by rearranging your layout.

Comment: Hey, I went to this conclusion after trying a bunch of manipulations on different properties. I think I'll go for a programmatical but I posted here first in case someone has a tricks to achieve it without starting to override Resizing events =p